# Abordagem otimizada de verificar se existe uma determinada entrada no arquivo hosts do Windows

Tags: java, sistema-operacional, sistema-de-arquivos, redes

Possuo uma aplicação web Java com Applets que acessam serviços na web. Esses serviços são acessados através de um hostname específico (exemplo: `services.webapp.com.br`) configurado na aplicação. Sabendo que é a JVM do usuário que irá executar o código referente ao ciclo de vida dos Applets, cabe a essa JVM traduzir o host `services.webapp.com.br` em um endereço IP que será efetivamente utilizado pelos services.

Porém, pode acontecer do usuário editar seu `Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` e redirecionar o host `services.webapp.com.br` para outro IP que não seja o endereço dos meus serviços, logo, a aplicação não conseguirá acessá-los e um erro acontecerá.

Sei que além do `hosts` do Windows existem outras formas de redirecionar o tráfego para um IP diferente, porém, quero cobrir esse ponto pois sei que meus usuários costumam utilizá-lo.

Em outras palavras, preciso saber em tempo de execução, se existe alguma entrada para o host `services.webapp.com.br` no arquivo `hosts` da máquina do usuário que está utilizando meu Applet, para exibir um alarme caso seja verdade. Existe uma forma elegante de fazer essa implementação?
Em algumas horas de busca no Google, vi que a única solução seria ler diretamente o conteúdo desse arquivo utilizando as bibliotecas de I/O do Java como [neste exemplo](https://java.net/nonav/projects/hosts/sources/hosts/content/trunk/src/com/floatfrog/hosts/Hosts.java?rev=6), pois é algo de baixo nível do sistema operacional e foge do escopo do Java.

Desculpem pela não postagem de código, pois a minha maior dúvida está no conceito da implementação.

Comment: `(...) vi que a única solução seria ler diretamente o conteúdo desse arquivo utilizando as bibliotecas de I/O (...)` É isso mesmo. Qualquer outra solução que você encontre provavelmente faz exatamente isso por debaixo dos panos. `(...) é algo de baixo nível do sistema operacional e foge do escopo do Java (...)`. Experimente implementar isso em C ou Assembly antes de chamar a implementação em Java de baixo nível ;) e não, isso não foge em nada do escopo do Java. O framework e a linguagem foram feitos para casos como esse também.

Comment: Provavelmente eu acabe implementando por conta própria mesmo, pois fora a portabilidade entre os sistemas baseados em Mac, Windows e Linux, não vejo grandes desafios a ponto de haver uma grande mudança no tempo de desenvolvimento caso eu encontre um framework. Não chamei a implementação em Java de baixo nível, o que quis dizer foi basicamente que, levando em conta a portabilidade do Java e custo de manutenção, não sei se devo esperar que o Java possua bibliotecas (próprias ou de terceiros) para alterar um arquivo específico, de um sistema operacional específico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me permite o comentário, esta é uma abordagem que pode ser considerada frágil. Um usuário mais experiente irá alterar as rotas diretamente no roteador e deixar o arquivo `HOSTS` intocado.

Algo mais seguro seria implementar um mecanismo de token encriptado que apenas os dois lados legítimos da aplicação poderiam interpretar. Assim, mesmo se o arquivo `HOSTS` for comprometido, o cliente só irá validar a conexão se um token válido for recebido.

Comment: Concordo com o ponto de vista à respeito da fragilidade, por isso utilizarei essa implementação apenas para troubleshooting e resoluções imediatas de problemas de conectividade, não utilizarei para basear o comportamento da minha aplicação. Achei sensacional a idéia do token, irei verificar se é possível implementar no servidor (administrado por outra equipe).